# "\c@subfigure already defined" when using subfig and subcaption

Tags: subfloats, subcaption, subfig

The following is my thesis preamble:

```
\documentclass[12pt,english]{article}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{graphicx} % for graphics
\usepackage{subfigmat}
%\usepackage[draft]{graphicx} % temporarily turn off graphicx
%\usepackage{subfig}
%\setcounter{lofdepth}{2}
%\usepackage{parskip}
\usepackage{caption}  % Enable figure captions or figure notes
\usepackage{subcaption} %Further enable sub captions
\usepackage{booktabs} %for table
\usepackage{amsmath} %for equations and mathematical symbols
\usepackage{amssymb} 
\usepackage{rotating} %for table rotation
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{float} % allow tables to self adjust
\usepackage{morefloats}
\usepackage[flushleft]{threeparttable}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{hyperref} % allow hyper referencing
\usepackage{breakcites}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{enumerate} % to get all that enumeration offers
\captionsetup{font=footnotesize}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage[round]{natbib} % for bibliography
%\bibliographystyle{cambridgeauthordate}
\usepackage{apalike}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%\usepackage[natbibapa]{apacite} % load "apacite" with option "natbibapa" 
%\bibliographystyle{apacite} % specify the bibliography style

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

%{plainnat} % regular bibliography
\usepackage[usenames, dvipsnames]{color} % coloring fonts
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{esint}
\usepackage[toc,page]{appendix}
\renewcommand{\cite}{\citeyear}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}
\newtheorem{corollary}{Corollary}
\newtheorem{assumption}{Assumption}
\newtheorem{definition}{Definition}
\newtheorem{proposition}{Proposition}
\makeatletter
\providecommand{\tabularnewline}{\\}
\usepackage{psfrag}\usepackage{multirow}\@ifundefined{definecolor}{\usepackage{color}}{}
\usepackage{colortbl}\usepackage{float}\usepackage{bm}\usepackage[metapost]{mfpic}
% Tree-saver - if turn this on you lose page numbers
 \setlength{\textwidth}{8.276in}
 \setlength{\textheight}{11.405in}
 % Allow 1 in margin on each side and nothing else
 \addtolength{\textwidth}{-2in}
 \addtolength{\textheight}{-2in}
 \setlength{\oddsidemargin}{0pt}
 \setlength{\evensidemargin}{\oddsidemargin}
 \setlength{\topmargin}{0pt}
 \addtolength{\topmargin}{-\headheight}
 \addtolength{\topmargin}{-\headsep}
 \newcommand{\ds}{\displaystyle}
 \newcommand{\bs}{\boldsymbol}
  %\pagenumbering{roman}
 \parindent=0pt
 \parskip=5pt
 \def\@cite#1#2{{#1\if@tempswa , #2\fi}}
 \def\@biblabel#1{}
 \def\ph#1{\phantom{#1}}
 \renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.0}

 \title{}
\author{}

\usepackage{babel}

\date{\today}
%\usepackage{calc} % To reset the counter in the document after title page

\makeatother

\begin{document}

\maketitle
\begin{abstract}
```

I must use `subfigure` package for

```
\begin{figure}[!ht]
\setlength{\lineskip}{1ex}% increase spacing
\centering
\subfloat[1998:1]{\includegraphics[width=.3\textwidth]{A1}}%
\hspace{\fill}
\subfloat[1998:2]{\includegraphics[width=.3\textwidth]{A2}}%
\hspace{\fill}
\subfloat[1999:1]{\includegraphics[width=.3\textwidth]{A3}}%
\hspace{\fill}
\subfloat[1999:2]{\includegraphics[width=.3\textwidth]{A4}}%
\hspace{\fill}
\subfloat[2000:1]{\includegraphics[width=.3\textwidth]{A5}}%
\hspace{\fill}
\subfloat[2000:2]{\includegraphics[width=.3\textwidth]{A6}}%
\hspace{\fill}
\subfloat[2001:1]{\includegraphics[width=.3\textwidth]{A7}}%
\hspace{\fill}
\subfloat[2001:2]{\includegraphics[width=.3\textwidth]{A8}}
\hspace{\fill}
\subfloat[2002:1][![enter image description here][1]][1]{\includegraphics[width=.3\textwidth]{A9}}
\hspace{\fill}
\subfloat[2002:2]{\includegraphics[width=.3\textwidth]{A10}}
\hspace{\fill}
\subfloat[2003:1]{\includegraphics[width=.3\textwidth]{A11}}
\hspace{\fill}
\subfloat[2003:2]{\includegraphics[width=.3\textwidth]{A12}}
\caption{\label{figure12} Dynamic crisis transmission maps from 1998-2003}
\end{figure}
```

But I end up getting errors as follows:

```
    LaTeX Error: Command \c@subfigure already defined.

Or name \end... illegal, see p.192 of the manual.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.113 \newcounter{subfigure}
                            [figure]
Your command was ignored.
Type  I <command> <return>  to replace it with another command,
or  <return>  to continue without it.
```

And some more errors as attached

[image]

How can I get rid of these errors?

Comment: You load `subfig` and `subcaption`, both are incompatible with another. Overall, the template you are using is just bad. Have a look at https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Scientific_Reports

Comment: Off-topic: in your shown screenshot of overleaf I can see the complete url to reach your project :-( I do not know, I did not try, to open it. Please do not show this url, wipe it out in the image or just do not add it in the screenshot ...

Comment: This is unrelated to overleaf, that just happens to be where you are running latex.

Comment: Thank you so much everyone.

Comment: Johannes_B, what do you suggest me to use instead of subgif and subcaption? subfig is essential for me if not subcaption.

Comment: Can you guys suggest me a cleaner preamble allowing me to fix the preamble here.

Comment: I believe this is a separate question an noone will be able to answer this within the comments here

Comment: @sheß yap, this is another issue

Comment: @Johannes_B what can I do to clean up preamble from the example here?

Comment: **Do only use/call packages you know and you need** for your document ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use the subcaption package. Instead of `\subfloat[]{}` use `\subcaptionbox{}{}`.

The subcaption documentation is exceptionally good; you should read it. https://ctan.org/pkg/subcaption?lang=en

```
\begin{figure}[!ht]
...
\subcaptionbox{1998:1}{\includegraphics[width=.3\textwidth]{A1}} \\
\subcaptionbox{1998:2}{\includegraphics[width=.3\textwidth]{A2}} \\
...
\caption{\label{figure12} Dynamic crisis transmission maps from 1998-2003}
\end{figure}
```

I also think it doesn't make sense to use both `\centering` and all of those `\hspace{\fill}` commands.

Comment: Well,  I created the comparison in the MWEB, that you can get into with the link, https://www.overleaf.com/3391682762fdwvbmrpzhrh and also edit. subcaptionbox did not make things better. Please have a look and tell me or make change

Comment: You have to remove `\usepackage{subfig}` and `\usepackage{subfigmat}`. See @Kurt's answer for an excellent solution.

Answer (score 5):

To solve your issue and to get a minimal working example you can delete most of your commands in your preamble.

For me it seems you simply copied parts of other tex files in the internet and/or collegues **without knowing** what the copied tex code does. That is the badest way to tex ...

General rule: **Do only use code you understand.** Do only use package you **had read the documentation** (type `texdoc subcaption` to get the documentation of package `subcaption` displayed)!

Now please have a look to the following mwe:

```
\documentclass[12pt,english]{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{babel}

\usepackage[showframe]{geometry} % <====================================

\usepackage[usenames,table,dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{graphicx} % for graphics
\usepackage{caption}  % Enable figure captions or figure notes
\usepackage{subcaption} %Further enable sub captions <==================
\captionsetup{font=footnotesize}

\usepackage{hyperref} % allow hyper referencing

\title{Title}
\author{Author}
\date{\today}


\begin{document}

\maketitle
\begin{abstract}
abstract
\end{abstract}

\begin{figure}[!ht]
%\setlength{\lineskip}{1ex}% increase spacing
  \centering
  \subcaptionbox{1998:1}{\includegraphics[width=.3\textwidth]{example-image-a}} 
  \subcaptionbox{1998:2}{\includegraphics[width=.3\textwidth]{example-image-b}} 
  \subcaptionbox{1999:1}{\includegraphics[width=.3\textwidth]{example-image-c}} 

  \subcaptionbox{1999:2}{\includegraphics[width=.3\textwidth]{example-image-a}} 
  \subcaptionbox{2000:1}{\includegraphics[width=.3\textwidth]{example-image-b}} 
  \subcaptionbox{2000:2}{\includegraphics[width=.3\textwidth]{example-image-c}} 

  \subcaptionbox{2001:1}{\includegraphics[width=.3\textwidth]{example-image-a}} 
  \subcaptionbox{2001:2}{\includegraphics[width=.3\textwidth]{example-image-b}} 
  \subcaptionbox{2002:1}{\includegraphics[width=.3\textwidth]{example-image-c}} 

  \subcaptionbox{2002:2}{\includegraphics[width=.3\textwidth]{example-image-a}} 
  \subcaptionbox{2003:1}{\includegraphics[width=.3\textwidth]{example-image-b}} 
  \subcaptionbox{2003:2}{\includegraphics[width=.3\textwidth]{example-image-c}} 

\caption{\label{figure12} Dynamic crisis transmission maps from 1998-2003}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

The blank line after three example-images generates a new line so you get three sub figures aranged in one line.

The result is:

[image: resulting sub figures]

Please see that I used option `showframe` for package `geometry` to visualize the typing area and margins. To adjust the margins use `geometry` (`texdoc geometry`) and do not use the old fashioned commands like `\setlength{\textwidth}{8.276in}` etc ...

Please see the correct order of calling packages (in most cases `hyperref` is called last!) ...